# Sublime text 2 linking to hosted libraries - is there a quicker way?

Tags: dependencies, package, sublimetext2

In a lot of my projects I use things like jQuery, Google maps, d3js etc. 
To get jquery I have to add the following to my header:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>`

Or to get d3js, I have to add:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

I find it time consuming to constantly have to keep looking up these URLs and I'm sure there must be a better way.

Is there a way I could do something where I type `script:jquery`, press tab and the script tags with the correct link would be created? And `script:d3js` would also create the script tags but this time with http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js as the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Sublime's [snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html). Something along the lines of

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>script:jq</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

should work in any HTML document when you type `script:jq` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>.